# C++/JSON Only one top level item allowed

Tags: c++, json, object

Seems like I'm writing my objects wrong but I have looked at many examples and I've still gotten the same issue. Reason why Im doing the Staff + StaffID is so I can then reference that object if that makes sense.
**The json object details are dependent on what the user inputs**

**Im using the nlohmann/json.hpp library**

```
    staff = {"Staff " + staffID, {
        {"First Name", first_name},
        {"Last Name", last_name},
        {"Age", age},
        {"StaffID", staffID},
        {"Phone", staff_phone},
        {"Skill 1", skill_1},
        {"Skill 2", skill_2},
        {"Skill 3", skill_3}
    } };

myFile << setw(4) << staff << endl;
myFile.close();
```

And the outcome in my json file, with the top entry being okay:

```
[
    "Staff 1",
    {
        "Age": 44,
        "First Name": "John",
        "Last Name": "Smith",
        "Phone": "97345345",
        "Skill 1": "Dogs",
        "Skill 2": "Vet",
        "Skill 3": "Grooming",
        "StaffID": "1"
    }
]
[
    "Staff 2",
    {
        "Age": 38,
        "First Name": "Jane",
        "Last Name": "Smith",
        "Phone": "9835735",
        "Skill 1": "Cats",
        "Skill 2": "Surgery",
        "Skill 3": "Grooming",
        "StaffID": "2"
    }
]
```

**Updated: More details**
The function is within a class, that function gets called within a while loop for a menu that allows the user to add staff, when user selects 'Add Staff' the add_info_staff function within the class.

```
class infoStaff
{
protected:


    json staff;
    char first_name[50];
    char last_name[50];
    int age;
    string staffID;
    string staff_phone;
    string skill_1;
    string skill_2;
    string skill_3;




public:
    void add_info_staff(void)
    {

        ofstream myFile("staff_j.json", ios::app);


        cout << "Please enter the first name:  " << endl;
        cin >> first_name;

        cout << "Please enter the last name:  " << endl;
        cin >> last_name;

        cout << "Please enter the age:  " << endl;
        cin >> age;

        cout << "Please enter the staff ID:  " << endl;
        cin >> staffID;

        cout << "Please enter the staff's phone number:  " << endl;
        cin >> staff_phone;

        cout << "Please enter skill 1 :  " << endl;
        cin >> skill_1;

        cout << "Please enter skill 2 :  " << endl;
        cin >> skill_2;

        cout << "Please enter skill 3 :  " << endl;
        cin >> skill_3;

        staff = {"Staff " + staffID, {
            {"First Name", first_name},
            {"Last Name", last_name},
            {"Age", age},
            {"StaffID", staffID},
            {"Phone", staff_phone},
            {"Skill 1", skill_1},
            {"Skill 2", skill_2},
            {"Skill 3", skill_3}
        } };

    myFile << setw(4) << staff << endl;
    myFile.close();

    }
};
```

Comment: Is the expected outcome `["Staff 1" , {...}, "Staff 2", {...}]`? If so, you will have to show a bit more of your program (the loop that accepts user input, converts to JSON and writes it to a file)

Comment: I added some more details if that helps Botje :) Thanks either way

Comment: Thanks Scheff!  might have to look into arrays :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply output multiple arrays to a file and expect it to be a valid JSON document. A JSON document must have one top level value, for instance

```
[
[
    "Staff 1",
    {
        "Age": 44,
        "First Name": "John",
        "Last Name": "Smith",
        "Phone": "97345345",
        "Skill 1": "Dogs",
        "Skill 2": "Vet",
        "Skill 3": "Grooming",
        "StaffID": "1"
    }
],
[
    "Staff 2",
    {
        "Age": 38,
        "First Name": "Jane",
        "Last Name": "Smith",
        "Phone": "9835735",
        "Skill 1": "Cats",
        "Skill 2": "Surgery",
        "Skill 3": "Grooming",
        "StaffID": "2"
    }
]
]
```

would be correct, as you now have one array at the top level.

I can't tell you what you are really after, but you need to come up with structure like this and use the API accordingly.